# После публикации приложение в плей маркет пишет: Приложение не поддерживаеться на этом устройстве

Tags: android, playmarket

Вот настройки приложение

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tj.bitmaster.navinservices"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

Comment: а какой у вас android? покажите еще манифест без тега `application`

Comment: видимо `camera2api`не поддерживается устройством

Comment: [Cсылка на манифест](http://novation.tj/services/AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: Ясно попробую убрать, Спасибо))